# v-model value update issue when passed prop value from parent to child

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am passing an object 'item' from parent to 'child' component. It works just fine. Please refer [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rczuymss/50/).

As you change the values from dropdown, it updates the UI. My issue is that the same exact code does not work in my application (running locally on my machine). I even tried adding `{{item.type}}` in html, but it does not change (sticks to original value). One thing I noticed that, if I put `@change='onChange'` and printed the value in `onChange` method and it prints updated value.

Really unable to find solution to fix this. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I can't imagine it is exactly the same. How is it set up locally?

Comment: Hey @BertEvans Thanks for your time. Please look at the code which is setup locally [here](https://pastebin.com/tx0PBSLt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are adding the `type` property to your model after the item was already bound to data, and [Vue cannot detect changes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) to properties added that way.

The fix is to make sure there is a `type` property on `item`,

```
item: {
  "direct_sale_price": "",
  "is_auction": true,
  "is_tender": false,
  "type": null
}
```

or to properly add it using [$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set).

```
created: function () {
  if (this.item.is_auction) {
    this.$set(this.item, 'type', 'auction')
  } else if (this.item.direct_sale_price) {
    this.$set(this.item, 'type', 'direct-sale')
  } else if (this.item.is_tender) {
    this.$set(this.item, 'type', 'tender')
  } else {
    this.$set(this.item, 'type', 'plain')
  }
}
```

Comment: ah. you can just remove them .  I did not add datepicker related stuff, since you have to install its plugin.  I will update it with more details.

Comment: Yes. Its there. please have a look [here](https://pastebin.com/X4M4jJkX) . Issue is with dropdown. changing the values is not getting affected. :(

Comment: @Pradeepb Now, the only thing I'm commenting out is the line importing getCookieId and the `created` handler in the parent and it works. I don't think `item-form` is your problem. Do you have errors on the console?

Comment: no errors at all(thats one of the reason I thought of taking help :) ). `getCookieId` is value coming from store(Vuex). and I am sure that its not an issue at all.

Comment: please check this https://github.com/pradeepb6/item-form. I have updated with data.

Comment: @Pradeepb Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. `$set` did the trick. Even though your solution of adding `type` to object worked in the example created by you(git), it did not work in my application. May be because the `item` object is getting the values from `http get` call. Thanks again :)